# Rails javascript is included but not executing on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

When I run the app locally, everything works fine. I only have 3 javascript files in the app:

*app/assets/javascripts/application.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

*app/assets/javascripts/social_posts.js*

```
//= require moment/moment
```

moment is located at `vendor/assets/javascripts`.

*app/assets/javascripts/social_posts_actions.js.coffee*

```
console.log 'hello'
# Format post dates
format_post_dates = ->
  $('time.moment').each ->
    dt = moment($(this).attr('datetime'))
    dtstr = dt.format('h:mm A')
    if dt.dayOfYear() != moment().dayOfYear()
      dtstr = dt.format('MMM Do, ') + dtstr
    $(this).html dtstr
    return
  return

add_edit_click_listener = ->
  $('.edit-social-post-action').click ->
    $('#socialPostMessage').val $(this).data 'message'
    $('#socialPostImageUrl').val $(this).data 'image-url'
    $('#myModal').modal()
    return
  return

# Add Handlers for the edit action
$(document).ready ->
  console.log 'hello doc.ready'
  add_edit_click_listener()
  return
```

When I view the source on heroku it shows my comments and `console.log` calls being updated in the javascript source but nothing is being executed.

Additionally, if I try calling moment() (one of the included libraries) from the console, the function isn't available.

I've tried pre-compiling my assets locally before pushing to heroku and that's not solving the problem.

This is rails 4

Comment: social_posts.js is in vendor folder? and moment is a function inside social_posts.js ? im correct?

Comment: @Marv-C no ... social_posts.js is under assets/javascripts, moment/moment is in the vendors/assets/javascripts folder

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution. Apparently because I didn't include tether, bootstrap was crapping out. Quite annoying :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` before you run `git push heroku master`? You need to compile your asset pipeline (images, css and js files) before pushing, otherwise they don't get uploaded to the production app.

Comment: I said in the original question that I precompiled it locally before pushing to test it out.